# What does white commit background in inteliJ mean?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have merged B into branch A but branch A has no commits with white background in InteliJ. I merged B into branch A at 3/31/2017 5:00PM. Thank you!

[image: commit branch B]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background color indicates commits that are included in the current branch (the one checked out at the moment). White background shows commits that are not present in the current branch.

Since you merged into A, A should be your current branch (unless some specific --fast-forward merge was used), and commits from it should not have a white background.

The screenshot, however, does not make it clear where the branch A is, where the branch B is and what branch is currently checked out.

> merged B into branch A at 3/31/2017 5:00PM

There is no such a merge commit on the screenshot. Maybe log is not refreshed properly?

Comment: screenshot above is branch B.i have known my problem. While i merged B into branch A at 3/31/2017 5:00PM, i forgot merged branch 20170329 into branch B. I don't understand "White background shows commits that are not present in the current branch." i have merged branch 20170329  into B. why my white background commit  isn't into branch B?